# opening MySQL query when the query selects columns of varchar datatype in delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-2009

I recently started with MySql, so i might be doing a begginers mistake. Any help is appreciated.

I connect the database in Delphi, define a query with columns of datatypes integer, decimal and varchar.

The problem is when I select a query in Delphi, and debug after opening query, the columns that are varchar does not appear as i if never selected them.

The driver for odbc connector is the latest mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.10

Comment: Show your mysql query and table schema please

Comment: @dzibul, please show your retrieval code so that we can give you a sensible answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Speculating**: Seems, you are using dbTables -> BDE -> ODBC -> MySQL data access path. BDE skips the fields with unknown data types. Probably Unicode character type is not supported by BDE.

**Possible solutions**:

- try to set ANSI character set for the connection in ODBC connection parameters;
- use dbGo / ADO data access components;
- use dbExpress components with MySQL dbExpress driver;
- use 3d party data access components.

Answer (score 4):

If you defined persistent fields for your `TQuery` in design mode, maybe you forgot to add the varchar (`TStringField`) field, or misspelled `FieldName`. Also make sure the filed is `varchar` rather than `nvarchar` (`TWideStringField`).

Another solution is to remove all persistent fields from your `TQuery`.

Answer (score 3):

Sample query:

```
SELECT anumber, adecimalnumber, avarchar FROM atable
```

Sample Delphi code (doing this from memory, so never mind small mistakes).

```
procedure Test;
var
  AQuery: TADOQuery;
  ANumber: integer;
  ADecimal: Real;
  AString: string;
begin
  AQuery:= TAdoQuery.Create;
  try
    AQuery.Connection:= SomeODBCConnection;
    AQuery.SQL.Text:= 'SELECT anumber, adecimalnumber, avarchar FROM atable';
    AQuery.Open;
    ANumber:= AQuery.FieldByName('anumber').AsInteger;
    ADecimal:= AQuery.FieldByName('anumber').AsFloat;
    AString:= AQuery.FieldByName('anumber').AsString;  << Gets the varchar.
    //Use AQuery.Next + test for AQuery.EOF to walk through rows.
  finally
    AQuery.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

It really not difficult at all to get varchar data.

Comment: the method that i use i exactly the same. The problem is, when I try to access the field that is varchar type, i get an exception. Instead of fieldbyname, i tried with Fields[i], but the fields that are varchar types does not exist. I think that the driver may be the problem, but i am using the latest :(